# Понижение репутации за голосование против

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против

Кто и почему может понижать рейтинг на единицу в случае голосования против какого-то ответа?

Пример: я проголосовал против ответа по причине того, что он никоим образом не помогал вопрошающему, а больше высказывал предположение, которое по правилам, насколько я понял, должны делаться в комментариях. На следующий день моя репутация была понижена на «-1» и при переходе из диалогового окна «Последние достижения» я попадаю именно на ответ, за который проголосовал против.

Comment: Когда голосуешь против ответа у тебя отнимается 1 балл репутации, а у того человека - 2 балла. То есть минусы на ответы не бесплатны (хоть и минимальны по стоимости)

Comment: Хе, а ведь закрыть вопрос как дубликат страницы в справке невозможно.

Comment: если не хочешь минусить то вот лайфхак: ставь тревогу, там настолько размыты причины что хоть одна да подойдет. +высока вероятность что вопрос закроют в итоге

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Один балл за минус вам сняла система. Это сделано специально, чтобы пользователи не увлекались минусованием.

Вот что сказано на этот счёт в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> Репутация понижается в следующих случаях:
>
> ...
>
> - вы проголосовали против ответа: −1;

Подобная мера [обосновывается](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17199/357761) так:

> Подобное происходит, потому что ваш минус снимает два балла репутации
>   *[с автора минусуемого сообщения — прим. пер.]*. Вы же при этом теряете один балл, чтобы не увлекались процессом. Мы же не хотим, чтобы кто-то забирал репутацию налево и направо без веских на то причин?
>
> Если вы считаете, что не готовы нести подобные небольшие потери за ваше мнение по какому-либо сообщению, смысла голосовать против нет вообще — об этом позаботятся другие участники, настроенные более категорично.
>
> ---
>
> *This happens because your down vote will remove 2 rep from that user. You lose 1 rep as well to prevent you from gaming the system. We couldn't let you go around taking rep away from others without making you consider if it's really worth it, could we?*
>
> *If you can't justify the small loss to express your opinion on the particular post, then there's no need to down vote. If other people feel more strongly than you, they'll take care of it.*

То есть минуса рассчитаны на применение в достаточно тяжёлых случаях, когда правки не помогают, а для тревоги ещё нет повода.

***P. S.*** То, что минус пришёл только на следующий день, связано с проведением пересчёта репутации каждый день в полночь по Гринвичу.

Comment: Спасибо большое, был на этой странице и какого-то лешего пропустил этот момент. Теперь все понятно.

Comment: Не стоило бы для достаточно тяжелых случаев умножить 1 и 2 на 10/100?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, логику работы движка определяем не мы, пользователи и администрация языкового раздела, а разработчики центрального сайта в офисе StackOverflow в США. Сомневаюсь, чтобы они согласились менять фундаментальный механизм, затрагивающий работу всех языковых разделов и тематических подсайтов. Однако при большом желании вы можете опубликовать ваше предложение на [подсайте, посвящённом работе всей сети StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (осторожно: английский язык).